# Comparar 2 objetos

Tags: angularjs

En mi app.js

```
var variable = {tipo: 2, variables: [20, 35, 50] };
$scope.test = variable;
$scope.test2 = angular.copy(variable);
```

En mi index.html

```
<input type="number" ng-model="test.tipo" />
<input type="number" ng-model="test2.tipo" />

<div ng-repeat="var in variables">
  <input type="number" ng-model="test.variables[$index]" />
  <input type="number" ng-model="test2.variables[$index]" />
</div>

<textarea ng-required=""></texarea>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el `textarea` sea obligatorio, si por ejemplo el valor de `test2.tipo` lo cambio por un **3**, pero si lo vuelvo a cambiar a **2** ya no sea obligatorio?

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, pero intentaré guiarte en cómo hacer que el `textarea` sea `required` o no dependiendo de algunos parámetros. En tu pregunta dices:

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el `textarea` sea obligatorio, si por ejemplo, el valor de `test2.tipo` lo cambio por un **3**, pero si lo vuelvo a cambiar a **2** ya no sea obligatorio.

Lo que entiendo de la anterior pregunta es que quieres que el `textarea` sea `required` si el valor de `test2.tipo` es desigual de 2.

Po lo tanto la menarea de lograrlo sería:

```
<textarea ng-required="test2.tipo != 2"></textarea>
```

Sin embargo, guiándome por el título de tu pregunta:

> Comparar 2 objetos

Supongo que lo que quieres es comparar el valor del parámetro `tipo` en los dos objetos. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código sitúa el parámetro `required` en el `textarea` solo si los parámetos `tipo` de los dos objetos son diferentes, si son iguales deja de ser requerido:

**Vista:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="myController">

        <input type="number" ng-model="test1.tipo" />
        <input type="number" ng-model="test2.tipo" />

        <textarea ng-required="test1.tipo != test2.tipo" ng-class="{'required': test1.tipo != test2.tipo}"></textarea>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Controlador:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.test1 = {tipo: 2, variables: [20, 35, 50] };
    $scope.test2 = angular.copy($scope.test1);

}]);
```

[Aquí tienes un jsfiddle funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/02sLew64/) con el anterior código.

**EDIT:** Siguiendo tu último comentario lo que deseas es comparar dos objetos completamente y si no son iguales entonces situar el parámetro `required` en el `textarea`. Lo más óptimo para lograr esto es usar la función [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) que te sirve para comparar dos objetos o dos valores. La técnica que he utilizado es llamar a un método en el `$scope` que actualice la variable `arequal` cada vez que lo desee (en este caso la actualizo cada vez que se varíen los valores de los `inputs`).

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.areequal = true;
  $scope.test1 = {tipo: 2, variables: [20, 35, 50]};
  $scope.test2 = angular.copy($scope.test1);

  $scope.compare = function() {
    $scope.areequal = angular.equals($scope.test1, $scope.test2);
  };

}]);
```

```css
.required {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="number" ng-model="test1.tipo" ng-change="compare()" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="test2.tipo" ng-change="compare()" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea ng-required="!areequal" ng-class="{'required': !areequal}"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es exactamente lo que necesito, imaginate que tenga 50 tipos, no puedo poner  ng-required="test1.tipo != test2.tipo || test1.tipo2 != test2.tipo2 ....", por eso necesito comprar el objecto y no un atributo del objeto, no se si me explicado bien

Comment: ¿Deseas que el `textarea` sea `required` cuando cualquier parámetro de uno de los objetos sea diferente de ese mismo parámetro en el otro objeto?

Comment: exacto, deseo eso

Comment: @sirdaiz, consulta mi última edición.

Comment: gracias era tan facil como eso :)

Comment: Sí, es un método sencillo también. Me alegro que te haya servido la solución. Un saludo ;)